# Apache POI Pivot Table Data Source

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I have a template excel file which already contains all diagrams and tables (empty of course), pivot tables and a namespace reference in the pivot tables `data source`-configuration (`PWRDaten` in my case).
They all refer to the first empty `data`-sheets, which provides all the data needed for the other sheets.

Now I am filling the first data-sheet programmatically which should automatically update all the different sheets. It is working fine in VISUAL BASIC...I am setting the namespace and an object range to select the relevant data:

```
objRange = objXLSSh.range(objXLSSh.cells(1, 1), objXLSSh.cells(47, 47))
objXLSSh.Names.Add("PWRDaten", objRange)
```

As I said this works perfectly fine.

But I am trying to make a JAVA solution with Apache POI...I already achieved the same logic like in my other solution, I also filled the first sheet correctly, but the only thing that is missing is this `namespace reference`. 
Can anybody tell me how I can achieve the result explained above?
So that I can pass the name reference `PWRDaten` and the object (cell) range to the file?
If that is not possible, how can I mark a cell area for all the sheets which need the data?

Again this worked fine for me in Visual Basic so I think there must be a solution in Apache POI too.

Thank you^^

PS: heres a screenshot of my data sheet and how the pivot tables reference is called [image]

Comment: Post your java code as well. Also I don't quite understand what exactly your issue is now. Do you not have a named range anymore after filling in the data or does the pivot table not update? What is the issue?

Comment: the named range is still the data source of the pivot tables in the excel file...I just dont know how to mark/create this named range programmatically in Java with apache poi...I dont know what code I should post:/ Isnt there a way to set a source for all pivot tables ?Like i did in Visual Basic?

Comment: apache-poi is by far not as powerful as VBA. I assume that the named range no longer exists because you use `createRow()` which overwrites all contents in that row and probably deletes the named range. You can still create a new pivot table programatically and use an `AreaReference` as datasource

Comment: First thank you for your help:) But I dont want to create a new pivot table...I wanna use the existing ones in the template and connect these to a named range (or static range like A10-U12) and I dont know how that works in Apache POI...But `AreaReference` is a good hint thank you:) Is there a way to modify this for an existing template?

Comment: Haven't tried is this actually works, but probably something along this: `CTWorksheetSource cacheSource = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition()
    .addNewCacheSource().getWorksheetSource();
  cacheSource.setSheet("sheetname");
  cacheSource.setRef("A1:C10");` It doesnt seem like you can use a named range as datasource though

Comment: Thank you!!!I will try it out and let you know if that worked :)

Comment: Okay worth a try, but it didnt work...the worksheetsource is null all the time. I have also tried to refresh the pivot tables automatically during load, and that worked, but all the pivot tables then loose their structure (columns etc.) and I have to manually put these in old order.